# Angular2 performance optimization

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working currently on a MEAN stack application and I started with with this [source](https://github.com/vladotesanovic/angular2-express-starter)

For production mod you need to comment out the

```
<script src="js/bundle.min.js"></script>
```

in the index.html file.

Within the tools folder there is a builder.js which is creating a bundle.min.js file. It is fast then development modus but still slover then Angular1x.

The builder.js file uses minify, mangle and rollup and in the end I will be the file 900KB. Well my question is how can I make the file smaller and the application faster?

Comment: I's suggest you use [angular-cli](https://cli.angular.io/) instead.

Comment: What is the advantage of angular-cli related to the performance?

Comment: That it applies best practices.

Comment: ok but I am speaking about three-hand-shaking, minifying the files into one bundle files.